# How to act more politely despite of beng mixed up?

Tags: phone-calls

Today again I called up a colleague and potential boss to ask about my application status to his department but totally forgot to greet him and ask how he is doing etc. 
Partly in our nerdy organization this is even maybe okay but I do not like myself behaving like that.

So how can I manage to force myself not just jump straight to the business after "Hi " but iterate 5-20 seconds in a polite "senseless" small talk which is though so important for normal communication?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it's phrased this sounds more like an *intra*personal problem (a problem existing about yourself) vs an *inter*personal problem (a problem related to communicating w/ other people).

Comment: @JessK. before I have managed to solve the intrapersonal problem still I experience the interpersonal problem so I thought I could get some advice here.